# Database automation using uiPath

Tags: automation, database-connection, export-to-csv

I am working on uiPath for one application. In that I want to fetch the data from the database and write it to a CSV file. I saw one workflow sample [here](http://www.uipath.com/examples/export-data-from-database-to-csv-file) I tried using that. But I got stuck. I am not able to connect to database. I have database installed on the same machine.

How can I set up configuration wizard db connection?

Comment: You need a database connection string that works. If you know it just add it in the connection string property.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get to shared mailbox in exchange using uipath to call a powershell script!!! I was stuck on that one for a while, but eventually got it working:):) no need to use outlook...

Answer (score 0):

You need a database connection string that works. If you know it just add it in the connection string property. Otherwise try to use the UiPath wizard to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

In Exchange it's not possible to get the messages from a shared mailbox with UiPath Exchange activities but it's possible with Outlook activities.